# Minimal images and deriving hostnames

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm developing a game server which is written in C++. I have it working but wanted to put it into containers. The containerized variant is working as well, however, there are some aspects to it that seem brittle.

Note this is my first foray into Docker, so I'm sure that I'm quite the dolt when it comes to the way of the Docker.

I've done a bunch of reading and experimentation but haven't determined if what I want to do is feasible.

My idealized state is to use `scratch` as my base image. I have a version that is working. The Dockerfile for this looks roughly like the following

```
FROM scratch

COPY ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
COPY libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
COPY libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
COPY libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
COPY libm.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
COPY libnss_dns.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2
COPY libnss_files.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
COPY libpthread.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
COPY libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
COPY group /etc/group
COPY passwd /etc/passwd
COPY nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf
COPY jks-server /root/jks-server

EXPOSE 8383

CMD [ "/root/jks-server/bin/jks-server", "--db_host=172.17.0.1", "--db_port=3307", "--host=172.17.0.3", "--resources_dir=/root/jks-server", "--env=testy" ]
```

where

`--host=172.17.03` tells which address for the server to listen on.

For me the issue is the hardcoded addresses. In particular, 172.17.0.3, which is the IP address of the container. From what I understand, this address could change depending on what I have running.

Ideally I'd love to do something like:

```
 CMD /root/jks-server/bin/jks-server --db_host=172.17.0.1 --db_port=3307 --host=`hostname -i` --resources_dir=/root/jks-server --env=testy
```

This works if I use ubuntu:16.04 as the base image. But then, the image size is much larger as well.

Is there a way for me derive the container's IP address whist being able to still use scratch? Or is it hardcode central?

Another alternative I know I can do is also listen on everything (0.0.0.0), but I really don't want to do that if I don't have to. Originally I thought it wouldn't be so bad, as I could define the inbound IP address via the ports flag (`-p`) on `docker run`.

For example, when binding to 0.0.0.0 (`--host=0.0.0.0`), I could run the container as

`sudo docker run --rm --name jks-server-runtime -p 192.168.1.11:8383:8383  -d jks-server-runtime`

In this case, 192.168.1.11 is a static IP I have currently designated on our local network for this particular test server.

If my technique is terrible, please let me know. I'm here to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: so one option is to use something like Docker swarm mode and the routing mesh. This would allow you to publish the port you want, and service discovery happens with any other service on the same software defined network. This is the most secure way to do this. You can find more info in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

Comment: Look at [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) for defining groups of containers and their environment, rather than trying to configure environment in the image itself

Comment: and [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/) if you want a small set of tools to go with your scratch container.

Comment: @ManoMarks thanks for the tip. I'll take a look. Lol, I guess I need to ready myself for the next hill of info to climb!

Comment: @Matt I'll look at Docker Compose. Do you happen to know if busybox is fine on performance? For example, I've read Alpine runs slower because of musl versus glibc. Eventually this will be going on an AWS instance running Ubuntu. Are there any issues with using those variants instead? As this is a game server, I'd sacrifice size for performance. Just trying to learn what my options are. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MobileBen Busybox would be a standalone, statically compiled binary that provides the extra linux utils you need. What busybox compiles against would not impact your server process linking to GNU libc.

Comment: @Matt, busybox FTW. A quick question, in case you know .. I believe they answer is yes. I'm currently running this in an Ubuntu image with VirtualBox/Vagrant running on a Mac. This container should be able to work properly on AWS (I'd be using an x86_64 instance). I do have it running from an executable built with the same setup. It does seem to run, but I haven't had a chance yet to put it through all the paces.

Comment: The image should be completely portable between linux's.  It would only be if you relied on some esoteric kernel stuff that Ubuntu has that AWS Linux (RHEL) doesn't. In any case you can run an Ubuntu image on AWS if there did happen to be something strange.

Answer (score 0):

A long as you are running the image in `--net=bridge` mode (which I believe is default..), if the container (image runtime) binds to `localhost` you can forward the container port `3307` to the host port `3307` with the runtime parameter `docker run -p 3307:3007 <image_name> ...` and all should be good...

Comment: From what I've read, `--net=bridge` is the default. I tried as you suggested. While it does bind, it does work. The calls do not seem to route properly and I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. if I run `lsof` I don't see any listeners.

Comment: In your code you have something checking for the flag `--db_host=172.17.0.1`. i'm suggesting you update the code to bind to 'localhost', and then forward the container's localhost:3307 -> actualhost:3707 via the `-p` flag in the docker run command - which should work fine.

Can you share your actual code and runtime command? Perhaps I am misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: What code in particular? For clarity, the issue is not with the ```---db_host``` or ```---db_port```,it's with ```--host```. Host defines what address the listener will listen on (name is terrible on my end). The port can be overwritten but it currently defaults to 8383 which is what I want right now. The run is listed above and is: `sudo docker run --rm --name jks-server-runtime -p 192.168.1.11:8383:8383  -d jks-server-runtime` where the runtime command coupled with it would be

Comment: `CMD /root/jks-server/bin/jks-server --db_host=172.17.0.1 --db_port=3307 --host=`hostname -i` --resources_dir=/root/jks-server --env=testy`

It's mangled a bit due to back ticks, a clearer version is listed above.

Comment: Two things:
* 172.17.0.1 is the gateway address for the default docker bridge network. There is a strong possibility that your container address is not that.. You can find in the `docker inspect <container ID>` info, OR cat it out of the /etc/hosts file inside the container (assuming you're based in some form of linux/debian container), or better yet.. just set --db_host=127.0.0.1 in the runtime command. (Binding to localhost INSIDE the container should be all you need, and then you don't need to worry about the specific IP.)

Comment: Thing 2: try removing the IP address from the docker run command `-p` flag. It should look like `-p 8383:8383`..

Comment: additional debugging idea:
Assuming you are building from a container with bash, once it is running, try attaching to it with `docker exec -it /bin/bash` from INSIDE the container you can poke around for system logs, IP addresses, or (install and run) curl commands against your server to eliminate the communication from host -> container to verify things are working as you expect..

Comment: I appreciate the efforts. I think there is a disconnect here. The `--db_host`` is not the issue. I've already figured out what the IP addresses are. For the container in this example it is 172.17.0.3 (which is why it was listed above). Moreover, I've already tried binding the executable to localhost. I effectively made a matrix of possible permutations early on, which is how I isolated what worked and what did not. Another option I can just do is add in a means for me to derive the containers IP address using boost.